# Oracle SQL Developer hides a portion of my XML output

Tags: xml, oracle, output, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i run my SQL query, Oracle hides a portion of the desired XML output. What should i do to get the desired result as shown below?

So here is my code:

```
SELECT
XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT
    XMLElement("test ",
      XMLAgg(
      XMLElement("Customers",
        XMLElement("id", c.id),
        XMLElement("name", c.name),
        XMLElement("gender", c.gender),
        XMLElement("bday", c.birth_date),
        XMLElement("mstatus", c.marital_status),
        XMLElement("income", c.income_level),
        XMLElement("limit", c.credit_limit)))
        )AS CLOB INDENT SIZE = 0) as XML   
        FROM customers c
        where rownum <= 10
```

The output i get is:

```
<test>
<Customers>
<id>13608</id>
<name>Ransom Wipple</name>
<gender>Male</gende
```

And the desired output would look like this:

```
<test>
<Customers>
<id>13608</id>
<name>Ransom Wipple</name>
<gender>Male</gender>
<bday>...</bday>
<mstatus>...</mstatus>
<income>...</income>
<limit>...</limit>
</Customers>
</test>
```

Comment: What is the version of SQL Developer you use? I cannot reproduce this with default settings and `select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from all_tables') from dual`: I can see all the data after click on pencil icon.

Comment: I'm currently using  Version 19.2.1.247 of Oracle IDE. When using xmlgen i have the same problem where it just stops. When clicking the  pencil icon it just clears (Ctrl+Shift+D) all the Script output..

Comment: No I'm about pencil icon inside the grid. When you double click on the cell in grid there's a pencil icon at the right side. I hope you use `F9` or `CTRL+Enter` to execute the script, not `F5` (which executes all the scripts inside the current window via SQL*Plus). xmlgen was there to reproduce the issue with some large dataset, because looked like the problem is in LOB size.

Comment: Ok, it looks like i'm a cookie. Running the script with F9 and then pressing the pencil actually showed the desired result. Thank you for your time, i just want to be done with this project and never touch sql again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `set long` to a larger value:

```
sho long
long 80

with rws as (
  select level rn, lpad ( level, 10, '0' ) v
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 5
)
  select xmlserialize ( document  
           xmlelement ( "root", 
             xmlagg ( 
               xmlelement (
                 "Data", 
                 xmlelement ( "rn", rn ),
                 xmlelement ( "v", v )
               )
             )
           )
           as clob indent size = 0
         )
  from   rws;
  
XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTXMLELEMENT("ROOT",XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("DATA",XMLELEMENT("RN",RN),XMLELEMENT("V",V))))ASCLOBINDENTSIZE=0)   
<root>
<Data>
<rn>1</rn>
<v>0000000001</v>
</Data>
<Data>
<rn>2</rn>
<v>00000000 
  
set long 100000

with rws as (
  select level rn, lpad ( level, 10, '0' ) v
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 5
)
  select xmlserialize ( document  
           xmlelement ( "root", 
             xmlagg ( 
               xmlelement (
                 "Data", 
                 xmlelement ( "rn", rn ),
                 xmlelement ( "v", v )
               )
             )
           )
           as clob indent size = 0
         )
  from   rws;
  
XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTXMLELEMENT("ROOT",XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("DATA",XMLELEMENT("RN",RN),XMLELEMENT("V",V))))ASCLOBINDENTSIZE=0)                                                                                                                   
<root>
<Data>
<rn>1</rn>
<v>0000000001</v>
</Data>
<Data>
<rn>2</rn>
<v>0000000002</v>
</Data>
<Data>
<rn>3</rn>
<v>0000000003</v>
</Data>
<Data>
<rn>4</rn>
<v>0000000004</v>
</Data>
<Data>
<rn>5</rn>
<v>0000000005</v>
</Data>
</root>
```

Comment: It is suitable for SQL*Plus, but SQL Developer uses JDBC drivers and internal processing of the data grid, so there should be something in IDE settings. In some IDE there's a limit on the preview size of LOB columns, but I didn't find something similar in SQL Developer.

Comment: `set long` applies in SQL Developer when you execute in script mode (F5); the output in the question is 80 characters long, which matches the default for this, so I'm guessing that's the mode the OP used. Plus the data grid includes ellipsis to show there's more output when it trims, which isn't in the question.

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't think that way because `F5` is not very usable for data retrieval tasks. Maybe it will be good to add information about `CTRL+Enter` to present another and more nice-looking way of doing `select`s in SQL Developer. Also it delays LOB preview as long as I know, which may save some time and space at the screen